# Configuring Spring Integration XML in resources.xml from Config.groovy

Tags: grails, groovy, spring-integration

I have a Grails app that has some small UI components and domain access, but mostly it is running a Spring Integration process to poll and read emails and process the results.

I want to be able to configure the email target based on environment.

I have the following Spring Integration XML snippet in `resources.xml`:

```
<mail:inbound-channel-adapter id="imapAdapter"
          store-uri="imaps://myEmailAddress:myPassword@imap.gmail.com/INBOX"
          java-mail-properties="javaMailProperties"
          channel="receiveEmailChannel"
          should-delete-messages="false"
          should-mark-messages-as-read="true"
          auto-startup="true">
    <int:poller max-messages-per-poll="1" fixed-rate="15" time-unit="SECONDS">
    </int:poller>
</mail:inbound-channel-adapter>
```

I have the following environment specific configuration snippet in `Config.groovy`:

```
environments {
    development {
        email.store.ui = 'imaps://myDevEmailAddress:myDevPassword@imap.gmail.com/INBOX'
    }
    test {
        email.store.ui = 'imaps://myTestEmailAddress:myTestPassword@imap.gmail.com/INBOX'
    }
    production {
        email.store.ui = 'imaps://myProdEmailAddress:myProdPassword@imap.gmail.com/INBOX'
    }
}
```

How do I tie the `email.store.ui` definition in `Config.groovy` to the `store-ui` attribute in `resources.xml`?

Comment: can you set the store-uri set to reference that you define in resources.groovy? just a thought

Comment: @chrislovecnm I've looked at adding an `email.store.ui` reference in the `store-ui` parameter, but I can't find an example of what the syntax for that would be.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Grails sets up a `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer` that takes its values from `Config.groovy`, so the normal Spring property placeholder syntax should work

```
store-uri="${email.store.ui}"
```

Comment: Thanks Ian... I just figured it out myself and beat you to the post by 9 seconds. ;-) I appreciate you taking a look. I gave you credit for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I guess I should have read to the bottom of the page... The answer is in section [15.5 Property Placeholder Configuration](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/spring.html#propertyPlaceholderConfiguration)

I just needed:

```
<mail:inbound-channel-adapter id="imapAdapter"
          store-uri="${email.store.ui}"
          java-mail-properties="javaMailProperties"
          channel="receiveEmailChannel"
          should-delete-messages="false"
          should-mark-messages-as-read="true"
          auto-startup="true">
    <int:poller max-messages-per-poll="1" fixed-rate="15" time-unit="SECONDS">
    </int:poller>
</mail:inbound-channel-adapter>
```

Thanks for the nudge.