# Reference grailsApplication in resources.xml or other xml

Tags: spring, grails

Is there any way to reference `grailsApplication` from either resources.xml or a different xml file that is imported by resources.groovy?

For example, I am wiring up some beans in foo.xml that will be imported in resources.groovy. I would like to pull in some values from the external config, so it would be nice if I could do something like:

```
<bean id=fooBean class="com.beans.foo.FooBean">
    <property name="exVar" value="${grailsApplication.config.some.path.to.ext.variable}"
</bean>
```

I've done this quite a bit in resources.groovy, so was wondering if there were a way to get at this object from xml. Thanks!

Comment: That depends what is processing the `resources.xml` context file. Do you have a normal `ApplicationContext`?

Comment: I'm not sure I know what you mean by "normal". This is a Grails application so the ApplicationContext is managed by the framework.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at this [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12148681/configuring-spring-integration-xml-in-resources-xml-from-config-groovy) you can use:

```
<bean id=fooBean class="com.beans.foo.FooBean">
    <property name="exVar" value="${some.path.to.ext.variable}"
</bean>
```